# linux screencapture/screencasting application that can cope with switching desktop managers

Tags: linux, screen-recording

Hi I want to record videos (about going back to linux) and specifically I want to try the OS with the different desktop envs Gnome/LWDM/Plasma etc.so want to be able to record my screen whist I either logout or switch user. I guess this would be possible if the capture software is running as a service/other user? Ideally I would be able to record the terminal output of a non windowed env also.

I wonder if this is possible with any current tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think any screencasting tool will suffice (Vokoscreen, OBS Studio etc), they basically use ffmpeg to record screen. There are some complexity while using Wayland as it enforces tighter security so no window can capture other window. But OBS Studio can use PipeWire to workaround this.

About non-graphical env, use ASCIInema, it is purely texual format to record terminal output.

Logging out will kill the process, switch user instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions will give it a go..